# How to add multiple tabs in iPhone app storyboard?

Tags: iphone, tabs, storyboard

I am trying to develop an app with multiple tabs.

The main screen has 2 tabs with tableViews when I select one row from any of the two tabs, it should not display these 2 tabs, instead I want to display 3 different tabs (see the image).

[image]

How can I do this? If I add another `Tab Bar Controller` it shows 3 new tabs under the first 2 tabs (i.e. 5 tabs on one screen).

Comment: I think you might just have to switch out your tabs programatically...

Comment: This is not easy to do, and for a good reason: it is a bad design choice. Tabs are meant to be different sections of your app accessible independently. For this reason, you can't put a UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController.